# Calculating the centroid of a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, centroid

Hope doing well and being healthy. I have a basic question on centroid of tetrahedrons.

> Are the coordinate of the centroid always the averages of $x$ and $y$ and $z$, by which I mean
> $$\frac14(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4),\quad\frac14(y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4),\quad\frac14(z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4)$$

(For example, MBD Alchemie's YouTube video ["Centroid of a Tetrahedron"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Infxzuqd_F4) shows it.)

I always see that people consider a $3:1$ ratio. Is it valid for all the tetrahedrons? I mean in case of having very flat tetrahedrons with enequal side tangles, can the centroid be calculated using this simple equation?
To make my request a more clear, I have uploaded a photo of an irregular tetrahedron here:

[image]

In advance, I do appreciate any response.

Comment: Short answer: yes. It's easier to understand  the corresponding formula for triangles. Check it for scalene triangles.

Comment: Dear @EthanBolker, By yes you mean I can use this simple equation to find the centroid of irregular tetrahedrons? Sorry, I am new in this field, thats why I ask too much basic questions.

Comment: Yes it is that simple. 3d has not complicated the situation basically.

Comment: Dear @Narasimham, I do appreciate your contribution.